# How can I perform discrete optimisation of a variable over a data set

Tags: optimization, modeling, constraint

This question relates directly to a dataset I've generated for Fantasy Premier League, but I'm also curious how I can apply this to a more general case.

**Data**

I have a list of premier league players, and for each player ***p*** I have calculated a predicted score ***s*** for that player over a period of time.

Each player inherently has a type ***t***, ranging from 1-4, and a team ***m*** ranging from 1-20. Each player also has an inherent cost ***c***.

**Constraints**

I can construct a team of consisting of 15 of these players. I am constrained by the number of players I can choose from each type ***t*** and team ***m*** such that, the team must have:

- 2 players of type ***t***=**1**
- 5 players of type ***t***=**2**
- 5 players of type ***t***=**3**
- 3 players of type ***t***=**4**
- no more than 3 players from any one team ***m***
- a total cost ***sum(m)* <=** some budget value ***B***

**Problem**

How can I create a team which maximises the sum of predicted scores ***sum(s)*** such that all constraints have been met. The brute force approach of generating every allowed team is not viable.

Answer (score 5):

What about the following model:

Let $P$ be the set of players. Each player $p$ has a type $t_p$, expected score $s_p$, team $m_p$ and cost $c_p$.

Let $x_p$ be a binary decision variable equal to 1 if $p$ is chosen for the team, $0$ otherwise.

The constraints are:

- Must choose 15 players - *note that in this case this constraint is redundant and can be omitted, as it's implied by the 4 constraints after it*: $$\sum_{p \in P} x_p = 15$$
- 2 players of type $t = 1$: $$\sum_{p \in P: t_p = 1} x_p = 2$$
- 5 players of type $t = 2$: $$\sum_{p \in P: t_p = 2} x_p = 5$$
- 5 players of type $t = 3$: $$\sum_{p \in P: t_p = 3} x_p = 5$$
- 3 players of type $t = 4$: $$\sum_{p \in P: t_p = 4} x_p = 3$$
- no more than 3 players from any one team $m$: $$ \sum_{p \in P: m_p = i} x_p \leq 3 ; \forall i = 1, \ldots, 20  $$
- Total cost below budget value $B$: $$\sum_{p \in P} c_p x_p \leq B$$

Finally, the objective function of maximixing sum of predicted scores will be $$\sum_{p \in P} s_p x_p. $$

There are several alternatives to implement and solve this model, such as:

- An AML such as AMPL or GAMS connected to a mathematical programming solver
- Via integer programming or constraint programming modules through programming languages like Python.
- Reading the sets and parameters in a spreadsheet and solve using the tools like Excel's Solver (if model size and complexity allow for it).

Comment: @RobPratt Thanks for pointing that out, answer edited to reflect this.